# How to calculate slope with plus minus uncertainty in the value

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following code gives a specific value of slope but I want to calculate it with some uncertainty like (1.95+_ 0.03) . How can I do that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

x= np.arange(10)
y = np.array([2,4,25,8,10,30,14,16,28,20])
z = stats.linregress(x,y)
print (z)
slope = z[0]
intercept = z[1]
line = slope*x + intercept    

plt.plot(x,y,'o', label='original data')
plt.plot(x,line,color='green', label='fitted line')

plt.xlabel("independent _variable")
plt.ylabel("dependentt_variable")
plt.savefig("./linear regression")
```

Comment: Specific value of what? what are you currently getting? help understand your code..

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for the slope using the formula described in detail [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/280/). From your code (assuming you are using the scipy.stats package), you can find the (1-α)% confidence interval as follows:

```
alpha = 0.05
CI = [z.slope+z.stderr*t for t in stats.t.interval(alpha/2, len(x)-2)]
print(CI)

# [1.9276895391491087, 1.9874619760024068]
```

To print the confidence interval in the form stated in your question:

```
halfwidth = z.stderr*stats.t.interval(alpha/2, len(x)-2)[1]
print('({} +/- {})'.format(z.slope, halfwidth))

# (1.9575757575757577 +/- 0.02988621842664903)
```

Alternatively, you could use the StatsModels package which has a built-in method to find the confidence interval. This is explained in the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400419/how-to-calculate-the-99-confidence-interval-for-the-slope-in-a-linear-regressio).

Comment: Is there any build in function like np.polyfit(x,y,1) that can do that? If you please explain this with a small piece of code it will be really helpful for me. I want slope in this form (-1.03+-0.06)

Comment: I've appended my comment.

Comment: actually I am want to ask how to find maximum and minimum of slope in linear regression

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the maximum and minimum of the slope if you are not referring to the confidence interval I showed in my answer. Using least squares regression on a given data set will always yield a single value for the estimate of the slope.